# Scroll to right using material react table

Tags: reactjs, material-react-table

Scroll to right using material react table when rendered

I'm using material react table for table display, I want table should be scrolled right side automatically when table is rendered or displayed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.